# Custom Docker for serverless lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, serverless

I'm writing a serverless lambda which requires a custom docker.
This is the dockerfile I wrote:

```
FROM node:14.16.1-alpine

RUN apk update && apk add git openssh-client vim python py-pip jq
RUN pip install awscli
RUN apk add automake autoconf libtool dpkg pkgconfig nasm libpng
RUN apk --purge -v del py-pip

RUN apk add --no-cache yarn

RUN rm /var/cache/apk/*

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./
RUN HOME=/kaniko/ yarn install --frozen-lockfile

RUN yarn build
```

Should I include a `CMD` as the end? to run serverless? or will it be done automatically?

Answer (score 1):

This [link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/demystifying-entrypoint-cmd-docker/) from the AWS blogs may be useful. It gives a good explanation about docker entrypoints.

> **Demystifying ENTRYPOINT and CMD in Docker**
> As you begin your Docker container creation journey, you might find yourself faced with a puzzling question: Should your Dockerfile contain an ENTRYPOINT instruction, a CMD instruction, or both? In this post, I discuss the differences between the two in detail, and explain how best to use them in various use cases you might encounter.

There is also this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html) from the lambda documentation that may help:

Here is an excerpt:

> **Lambda requirements for container images**
> To deploy a container image to Lambda, note the following requirements:
> The container image must implement the Lambda Runtime API. The AWS open-source runtime interface clients implement the API. You can add a runtime interface client to your preferred base image to make it compatible with Lambda.

Comment: but doesn't serverless framework already provide runtime API?

Comment: Post the images as text so it can be indexed, read by screen readers etc.